# Pagination in rails with infinite scroll from bottom to top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We have messages div having list of messages inside it, when a page loads then page should scroll to last message on page(i,e 10th message, each page having at-most 10 items).If we scroll up then next 10 message should append at the top to the messages list.

Comment: Share your trying code?

Answer (score 0):

As your question was not clear enough and there was no code, am assuming that you want the page to scroll to the bottom when it loads.

To do this you can go with javascript, am going with [Azazi's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29291223/7237147)

```
<script>

    setTimeout(printSomething, 1000);

    function printSomething(){
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            document.write("Hello World\n");
            document.write("<br>");
        }
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        setTimeout(printSomething, 1000);
    }
</script>
```